# How to pass employeeId coming from controller in JSP SQL Select Statement?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jsp

${employeeId} is showing properly if I put it in html tags (paragraph, anchor etc.) but is not working when I'm passing it through a sql prepared statement to select employee from database like: prepStatement.setInt(1, ${employeeId}). if I pass 1, 2, 3 etc. instead of ${employeeId} it works and show the related results this means my code is almost correct but it's not working with ${employeeId}, I tried adding single and double quotes around ${employeeId} but nothing works.

**EDITED:**

JSP file

```
<%
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:./MANAGER", "test", "password");

 Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

 String queryString = "SELECT * FROM OWNER WHERE EMPLOYEEID = ? ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";

 PreparedStatement pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);

 pstatement.setInt(1, ${employeeId});

 ResultSet resultset = pstatement.executeQuery();

 if(!resultset.next()) {
     out.println("Sorry, could not find that publisher. ");
 } else {
%>

<%= resultset.getString("employeeId") %>

<%
   }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `${employeeId}` is syntactically wrong because [there is no operator such as `$` in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Moreover, `PreparedStatement` does not know how to treat a JSTL tag.

If `employeeId` is an attribute present in the request object (e.g. set into the controller as `request.setAttribute("employeeId", 123)`), replace

```
pstatement.setInt(1, ${employeeId});
```

with

```
pstatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("employeeId")));
```

If `employeeId` is a variable declared and populated in the page itself (e.g. `<c:set var="employeeId" value="123"/>`), replace

```
pstatement.setInt(1, ${employeeId});
```

with

```
pstatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt((String)pageContext.getAttribute("employeeId")));
```

Comment: Thanks Arvind (Live and Let Live) for your reply, I'm fetching data using select sql statement in JSP not in Controller, that's why $ operator is I think correct. And I tried removing request.getParameter because employeeId isn't coming from a URL parameter, but it still not working, do you have any other method or a modified version of this method?

Comment: @MusabShakeel - In that case, you will have to get it from `pageContext`. I've updated my answer accordingly. In order to help you further, I will need some more code from your JSP to look into it.

Comment: @MusabShakeel - In your updated question, you have not posted where have you put a value in `employeeId`.

Comment: It's in the controller through a model.addAttribute using get auth employeeId function.

Comment: @MusabShakeel - Earlier you said that it's not in the controller and now you are saying that you are setting its value in the ontroller. Whatever case may be, my answer caters to both the requirements.

Comment: SQL statement is not in controller, employeeId is coming from controller.

Comment: @MusabShakeel - Go through the answer carefully. It has everything that you may need to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> and try